# Scroll down to load data using recycleview and SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout, onscrolllistener

We've been looking around for the implementation of the new material design swipe down to refresh on RecyclerViews with the loading circle coming down from bottom view same like new gmail app.i found so many things. But not getting new gmail app like example or demo .i already implement refreshlayout and recycleview.

But when scroll down to recycleview,how to put loading circle at the last of the record in recycleview. I want to get some idea to put in onscroll of recycleview.

```
recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(int arg0, int arg1) {

                //add some data but not to show loader.
                getDataFromDB();

            }
        });
```

Comment: What you mean `put loading circle at the last of the record in recycleview` ? Do you mean show a loading circle when reach to last record ?

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya yes.i want to put loader same like new gmail app.

Comment: New Gmail app is having `ContentLoadingProgressBar` added in footerview and not `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya arrrree.i want to just gmail like listview and scrolling functionality demo link.have you it?

Comment: I am confused,what you want to ask look at your title please.

Comment: The OP has noted that the Gmail app actually uses TWO methods for indicating refresh.  It uses BOTH the SwipeRefreshLayout AND it adds a second loading indicator to the bottom-most item if a user has scrolled to the bottom of available content.  I haven't done the second trick, but example the first trick is here:  https://github.com/dbleicher/recyclerview-grid-quickreturn

Answer (score 0):

hi If you wan't to develop such a kind of Layout then please follow this url, i was used it it's an awesome.

https://github.com/stormzhang/SwipeRefreshLayoutDemo

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap all your layouts with 
[pull to refresh](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html) component for that.
after `swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener` and set `swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);` when you send API call

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

[hear](https://github.com/captain-miao/RecyclerViewUtils) is awesome demo for both Scroll down to load data using recycleview and Swipe to RefreshLayout.